# Call service,factory in any where in the zf2 project

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am a newbie to zend framework. I am worrying how to call a service,factory other than from a controller (or class which is not extended **AbstractActionController**).

I am using the **ZfcUser** module to authenticate users. Now I want to check wheather a user logged or not inside the ZfcUser\Form\Base class. I am unable to call the **zfcUserAuthentication** factory which inside the **getControllerPluginConfig()** in **ZfcUser\Module**

Please some one help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking at is the concept of [`Dependency Injection`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection). Basically YOU need to make sure that the Services you create GAIN access to the Gateways or Services they need.

For example, if you have a Service that takes care about persisting your Entities (DataObjects) to the Database, then YOU need to make sure to "inject" the Database-Adapter into the ServiceObject.

Required Dependencies therefore should be set via Constructor injection, i.e.:

```
class MyService {
    public function __construct(DbAdapter $dbA) {
        // do stuff with $dbA
    }
}
```

And you create this via the ServiceManager

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'MyService' => function($sm) {
             $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
             $service   = new MyService($dbAdapter);
             return $service;
         }
    )
)
```

And lastly you access your service via the ServiceManager (probably somewhere in your controller).

```
public function someAction() {
    $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyService');
    // do stuff with $service
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I got the idea.

Comment: But how we can call the service in Constructor. When I tried I got fatal error. Could you please help in this.

Comment: @ManikThakur please open a new issue. The injection happens into the constructor and once it's injected properly you can access it. Make sure to paste the error into your own thread.

Comment: @Sam I just asked here because of this thread's title. Anywhere means it can also be in constructor.

Comment: @ManikThakur my point is: I have no idea what your problem is. The comment section inside a 5 year old thread is not the place to ask for help ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the services/classes that a given service/class depends on. In your case you should modify `ZfcUser\Form\Base` to either accept the class via the constructor or a setter function. Then you would modify the service factory that creates the instance of `ZfcUser\Form\Base` to inject the dependency.

For example:

ZfcUser\Form\Base

```
private $myDependency;

public function setMyDependency($dependency) {
    $this->myDependency = $dependency;
}
```

And if your using a closure in your service factory config something like:

```
'my_service_that_uses_zfcuser_form_base' => function($sm) {
    $form = new ZfcUser\Form\Base();
    $form->setMyDependency($sm->get('the_dependency_you_want'));
    return $form;
}
```

Avoid injecting the service manager, this is bad practice.